# Fragment state loss?

Tags: android, android-fragments

What exactly is a "State Loss" situation? can you demonstrate a full scenario(include some code) which will cause it?
I have read many tutorials(official and unofficial), blogs, stackoverflow questions/answers about the topic but never so an example that will cause an actual state loss and what actualy happens after the state loss occur.

I don't know the full steps to do in order to cause a state loss.
What I tried to do is:

1. An Activity which have a layout that contains a frame layout.
2. A Fragment which have a layout with an 'hello' text inside some TextView.
3. The Fragment is added with a fragment transaction to the above frame layout.
4. A scenario which the user press the home button and then a fragment transaction occurs which is commited using commitAllowingStateLoss() method.

Then I tried to do a configuration change but everything was ok.
Then I tried to just resume from background but also everything was ok.
Then I tried to a add the fragment to the back stack and do the commitAllowingStateLoss()
and then the above steps ,but when the configuration change occur or when I came back from background, and then I pressed the back button which did remove the transaction, meaning removing the fragment from the back stack which means no state loss occur.

So what is exactly that 'state loss'? how its affect what the user will see on the screen.
can you show a full state loss scenario?

EDIT: put some test code:

Activity code:

```
package com.example.statelosstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    //Just for test
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            addDummyFragment();             
        }
    }, 5000);
}

/**
 * Invoke this method after onSaveInstanceState has been called,
 * for example after user press android home button.
 */
private void addDummyFragment(){
    DummyFragment frag = new DummyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_frame, frag, frag.getClass().getName());

    // tried this also
    // transaction.addToBackStack(frag.getClass().getName());

    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}

}
```

**EDIT: STILL NO ANSWER -**
I tried to simulate things which I thought will cause a state loss and that I will see that state loss in the UI but couldn't simulate or cause any state loss situation. Please can somebody show a scenario which a state loss occurs and that it can be seen in the UI, meaning that the state loss really happen the an unexpected behavior really occurred.

Comment: See also: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Comment: Great article, but I read it already before(more than one time). There is no example of a real state loss and what actually happen when a state loss occur. I just can't imagine why its dangerous to use commitAllowingStateLoss()? I cant imagine a situation when it will really affect my code. Can you show a code and a scenario which will result in a UI weird behavior because of commitAllowingStateLoss() which of course will be used after onSaveInstanceState() has been called

Comment: @Alex Lockwood you are my last hope ;) for solving this.

Comment: What makes this not a state loss situation?  The commit is going to get thrown away when you expect it to be there (in a real-world situation).  What would the expected behavior be when committing a UI Fragment?

Comment: I dont understand you. When i commit it with commitAllowingStateLoss and, for example i am making a configuration change, then the commit was there, meaning the fragment that i added was there which means that no state loss actually happend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some state loss examples:

**1.** suppose u have a button and a textview. in code, u have defined integer i with initial value 0 which increments by one by cicking button and its value is displayed in the textview. suppose u have pressed button 5 times, then textview will be set to 0. That is **Integer lost its value** on screen change.

**Solution:** override onSaveInstanceState and put the value of integer. then retain the value of that integer in onResume or onCreate method.

**2.** Consider u have a todo listview. User add to dos in that listview dynamically. suppose user have added 3 items, then on screen rotation (or if app restarts), the listview will become empty.

**Solution:** Again in onSaveInstanceState, put the ArrayList. (Lists can be implemented as "Serializabe" or "Parcelable" and can be stored as a whole. U dont need to store every item of listview). then in onResume or onCreate method, get that listview.

**3.** All the edittexts in the screen will become empty when screen rotates.

What I understand about state loss in simple language is that whenever configuration changes (screen rotation or app restarts), the entire lifecycle of the activity is called. So, whatever was there which was not saved will be lost.

Well this reminds me of Nintendo's exit screen message, "Anything not saved will be lost".

Comment: What you described is very good but I already know it. My question was about fragment state loss and to be specifically about a transaction which can happen after the onSaveInstanceState has been called. For example: sending an http request and while waiting for response the user click the home button and after that the response arrive and a fragment transaction is occurring. I have put some code in question.

Comment: if i get it right, what u want is to do some stuff in onSaveInstanceState (recieving http request while user is away). i may be wrong but what my logic says is that after onSaveInstanceState, onPause, onDestroys methods are called. So a fragment that has been paused (or destroyed or detached) can do nothing. u can use asynctask instead to do stuff in background

Comment: and about backstack, it doesnt mean that fragment is alive in the background. even if u have used backstack to transact between fragments, its onPause and all those methods will be called. It only means that u can return back to this fragment by pressing back button from the next fragment (or any other fragment. that depends on how u have used back button)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. My part of code which send the http request is running in a background thread. on destroy will not be called(probably) because the user only pressed the home button. As I said to @Alex Lockwood: I just can't imagine why its dangerous to use commitAllowingStateLoss()? I cant imagine a situation when a state loss will really affect my code. Can you show a code and a scenario which will result in a UI weird behavior because of commitAllowingStateLoss() which of course will be used after onSaveInstanceState() has been called

Comment: ahh.. okay.. i get it now. u want to know haphazards of using commitAllowingStateLoss(). umm, i too dont have any such scenario in my mind. i will let u know when i will come across such situation.

Comment: I will glad if you try to do it. Thanks anyway.